# Connotation of "visceral"

Tags: meaning, connotation

I understand that "visceral" with respect to a reaction or feeling is a very intense one. But I haven't found an authoritative source that describes a visceral reaction as being an exclusively bad one. Examples:

**Visceral = bad?**

- Seeing an intruder in your home.
- Be suddenly and intensely repulsed by someone's comment.

**Visceral = good?**

- Being moved to tears after an unexpected photo of something good.
- Figuratively having your wind knocked out in a "love at first sight" situation.

Sorry my examples may not be as good as they could be. Does visceral mean just a bad feeling or can it mean a good feeling in your gut too?

Comment: What do the dictionaries say about the word *visceral* and what about those definitions would you like help in understanding?

Comment: Why do you think it would have a bad or good connotation?

Comment: I used it with a good connotation once and was told it was exclusively with a bad connotation. I believed that person until I looked it up in the OED online (subscription version). No mention of good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

The viscera are your gut, intestines, liver, kidneys, and so on -- your entrails.

A visceral reaction is one which somehow concerns your viscera. You can feel them as bodily sensations.

- It can mean a gut reaction. ("I *knew* he was the one who did it").
- It can mean a feeling consequential to an autonomic reaction (physical heartache, heart-wrenching lovelorn anguish, stomach-twisting grief, feeling sick at the sight of some horrific scene, an adrenaline rush on a fairground ride, *"butterflies" in your stomach*, *"bricking it"*)

Given our origins as a species, and ultimate fate as individuals, they rarely positive, but certainly can be. Similarly, they need not be intense, but usually are.